# Referencing data in cell upon monthly opening of file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is yet another thing I am trying to do in excel where I am keeping track of materials sold, the previous month data should auto-populate in a certain column (column M in attached picture) and I am able to put the data in the next column (column N in attached picture), to find the difference in both months (in column O).

[image]

I tried referencing through TODAY() function {as every month (1st week) this reports needs to be generated}, but didn't work out. Not conversant with VBA codes.

| Type of Material sold | Value/Qty for previous month | Value/Qty for this month | % Difference from previous month | Aug-22 | Sep-22 | Oct-22 | Nov-22 | Dec-22 | Jan-23 | Feb-23 | Mar-23 | Apr-23 | May-23 | Jun-23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Material 1 |  |  |  | 46 | 21 | 46 | 22 | 26 | 46 | 43 | 25 |  |  |  |
| Material 2 |  |  |  | 46 | 40 | 15 | 21 | 38 | 46 | 41 | 47 |  |  |  |
| Material 3 |  |  |  | 13 | 37 | 38 | 30 | 37 | 16 | 35 | 14 |  |  |  |
| Material 4 |  |  |  | 10 | 31 | 48 | 23 | 3 | 10 | 14 | 49 |  |  |  |
| Material 5 |  |  |  | 47 | 6 | 11 | 3 | 13 | 10 | 37 | 22 |  |  |  |
| Material 6 |  |  |  | 43 | 29 | 2 | 45 | 6 | 50 | 44 | 3 |  |  |  |
| Material 7 |  |  |  | 10 | 35 | 11 | 41 | 23 | 28 | 32 | 18 |  |  |  |
| Material 8 |  |  |  | 49 | 4 | 5 | 39 | 14 | 45 | 32 | 45 |  |  |  |
| Material 9 |  |  |  | 10 | 9 | 30 | 47 | 29 | 36 | 45 | 23 |  |  |  |
| Material 10 |  |  |  | 7 | 34 | 39 | 19 | 0 | 49 | 47 | 15 |  |  |  |

---

Scenario : If I were to use this file on the first week of April, Column (Value/Qty for previous month) should be auto populated with values from Column (Mar-23), like the following:

| Type of Material sold | Value/Qty for previous month | Value/Qty for this month | % Difference from previous month | Aug-22 | Sep-22 | Oct-22 | Nov-22 | Dec-22 | Jan-23 | Feb-23 | Mar-23 | Apr-23 | May-23 | Jun-23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Material 1 | 25 |  |  | 46 | 21 | 46 | 22 | 26 | 46 | 43 | 25 |  |  |  |
| Material 2 | 47 |  |  | 46 | 40 | 15 | 21 | 38 | 46 | 41 | 47 |  |  |  |
| Material 3 | 14 |  |  | 13 | 37 | 38 | 30 | 37 | 16 | 35 | 14 |  |  |  |
| Material 4 | 49 |  |  | 10 | 31 | 48 | 23 | 3 | 10 | 14 | 49 |  |  |  |
| Material 5 | 22 |  |  | 47 | 6 | 11 | 3 | 13 | 10 | 37 | 22 |  |  |  |
| Material 6 | 3 |  |  | 43 | 29 | 2 | 45 | 6 | 50 | 44 | 3 |  |  |  |
| Material 7 | 18 |  |  | 10 | 35 | 11 | 41 | 23 | 28 | 32 | 18 |  |  |  |
| Material 8 | 45 |  |  | 49 | 4 | 5 | 39 | 14 | 45 | 32 | 45 |  |  |  |
| Material 9 | 23 |  |  | 10 | 9 | 30 | 47 | 29 | 36 | 45 | 23 |  |  |  |
| Material 10 | 15 |  |  | 7 | 34 | 39 | 19 | 0 | 49 | 47 | 15 |  |  |  |

Upon entering the data in Column (Value/Qty for this month), the same values should be replicated in Apr-23 and the percentage difference between previous and present month displayed in Column ( % difference from previous month) i.e

My data for April is (Material 1 - 45, Material 2 - 15, Material 3 - 16, Material 4 - 4, Material 5 - 22, Material 6 - 8, Material 7 - 16, Material 8 - 65, Material 9 - 37, Material 10 - 9)

then it should show on entering the above like this below:

| Type of Material sold | Value/Qty for previous month | Value/Qty for this month | % Difference from previous month | Aug-22 | Sep-22 | Oct-22 | Nov-22 | Dec-22 | Jan-23 | Feb-23 | Mar-23 | Apr-23 | May-23 | Jun-23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Material 1 | 25 | 45 | 80.0 | 46 | 21 | 46 | 22 | 26 | 46 | 43 | 25 | 45 |  |  |
| Material 2 | 47 | 15 | -68.1 | 46 | 40 | 15 | 21 | 38 | 46 | 41 | 47 | 15 |  |  |
| Material 3 | 14 | 16 | 14.3 | 13 | 37 | 38 | 30 | 37 | 16 | 35 | 14 | 16 |  |  |
| Material 4 | 49 | 4 | -91.8 | 10 | 31 | 48 | 23 | 3 | 10 | 14 | 49 | 4 |  |  |
| Material 5 | 22 | 61 | 177.3 | 47 | 6 | 11 | 3 | 13 | 10 | 37 | 22 | 61 |  |  |
| Material 6 | 3 | 8 | 166.7 | 43 | 29 | 2 | 45 | 6 | 50 | 44 | 3 | 8 |  |  |
| Material 7 | 18 | 16 | -11.1 | 10 | 35 | 11 | 41 | 23 | 28 | 32 | 18 | 16 |  |  |
| Material 8 | 45 | 65 | 44.4 | 49 | 4 | 5 | 39 | 14 | 45 | 32 | 45 | 65 |  |  |
| Material 9 | 23 | 37 | 60.9 | 10 | 9 | 30 | 47 | 29 | 36 | 45 | 23 | 37 |  |  |
| Material 10 | 15 | 9 | -40.0 | 7 | 34 | 39 | 19 | 0 | 49 | 47 | 15 | 9 |  |  |

End of Scenario_____________________________________________________________

Comment: it seems to be an `INDEX/XMATCH` problem, difficult to provide additional help since the data is not in [table markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format. I would suggest also providing the expected output for the two scenarios you mentioned.